# You can't come back here once you leave/ you've left --- the difference in meaning

Tags: sentence-meaning

You can't come back here once **you leave**.

You can't come back here once **you've left**.

Do both the above sentences mean the same?

Answer (score 0):

They're different tenses, but they have no significant difference in meaning.

From [this website](http://en.bab.la/conjugation/english/leave), they are are simple present and present perfect (respectively).

According to various forms, this is common among the US and UK and both should be understood equally, although [you leave](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=you%20leave%2Cyou%27ve%20left&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cyou%20leave%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Byou%20leave%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BYou%20leave%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cyou%20%27ve%20left%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Byou%20%27ve%20left%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BYou%20%27ve%20left%3B%2Cc0) is far more common.

Comment: @Alancarmack whoops! I got a bit too focused on that chart there. Fixed it. Thanks!